# Redirect a download file from API server in Python

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 server: one backend for API and another one as web-frontend.
The backend is working and provides files:

```
#API class for the route in Flask
class DownloadDocument(Resource):

    def get(self):

        # accept the filename which must be downloaded in HTTP request.
        # That file is surely present in the directory

        filename = request.headers.get('x-filename')      
       
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename, as_attachment=True)
```

The web-frontend is currently getting the file in this way:

```
@app.route('/get_doc/<filename>')
@login_required
def get_doc(filename):
      sending = {'x-filename': filename}
      response = requests.get('http://<<api_server>>', headers=sending)
      return response.content
```

The result is that when I click download in the webpage (`http://<<frontend>>/get_doc/20201116003_895083.jpg`), I see the file as text and not downloaded.
For example, I see a big page full of that:

```
����]ExifII*����
```

I don't understand if the problem is in the frontend or in the backend.
In the frontend, I tried with *urllib.request.Request* or *requests.request*.
Any idea how to manage this kind of download? Probably is something related to mime interpretation, bytes download or buffer it locally.
Of course, I don't want to download the file in the web-frontend storage. I want to redirect it to the visitor.

Here are the headers from GET:

```
{'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=20201116003_895083.jpg', 'Content-Length': '574424', 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'Last-Modified': 'Tue, 01 Dec 2020 14:04:30 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=43200', 'Expires': 'Thu, 03 Dec 2020 02:34:51 GMT', 'ETag': '"1606831470.89299-574424-736697678"', 'Date': 'Wed, 02 Dec 2020 14:34:51 GMT', 'Server': 'Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.8.3'}
```

Comment: This question lacks details.  It's unusual to be using python `requests` library on the frontend.  Can you show a bigger code sample to demonstrate how you are getting this file to the browser?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good way to architect your application.  I think the Restful backend is intended to work with a Javascript frontend, rather than a separate Flask app which contacts the 'backend' with the `requests` library.  I'm not sure how this would behave in a larger app. The `requests` documentation [raises some prod considerations about timeouts](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) for example.  You may see some unforseen issues down the line when deploying this with a WSGI server. (imo)

However, with that considered, a quick fix for the actual issue would be to use the `flask.send_file` function to return the file.  This accepts a file pointer as the first argument, so you'll need to use `io.BytesIO` to convert the bytes object:

```
from flask import send_file
from io import BytesIO

@app.route('/get_doc/<filename>')
@login_required
def get_doc(filename):
      sending = {'x-filename': filename}
      response = requests.get('http://<<api_server>>', headers=sending)
      return send_file(BytesIO(response.content), mimetype='image/jpeg'
          #as_attachment=True
          )
```

You also need to provide the `mimetype` argument, as usually `send_file` guesses the mimetype based on the extension when a string like `'file.jpg'` is passed as the first arg.  Obviously that can't be done in this case.

You can also pass `as_attachment=True` if you want the user to receive a download prompt, rather that viewing the image in-browser.  This is all mentioned in the [`send_file` docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file).

Again, this feels like a hack.  Something seems off with using the `requests` library in this way.  Perhaps other SO users will be able to comment further on this.

Comment: Yes, it worked! I got the point. Currently I have to use this solution but I promise I will improve it in the future. Thank you very much for your support and fast reply!